# Javascript onkeydown listening on tag video

Tags: javascript, html, api, video

I would like to trigger the onkeydown event in the video tag
But I see that gives me no results I hope I understand and can help me... greetings.

```
document.querySelector("video").onkeydown = function (e){  
  switch(e.keyCode){
     case 65:
     console.log('code 65')
    break;  
  } 
}
```

This is my Code.

Comment: What browser are you using this in? The KeyboardEvent event a) deprecated and b) handled different depending on the browser you're testing your code in. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: Hello thank you for answering. I'm working on Chrome, the intention is to have the focus on the video tag and to do different tasks...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the keyboard events to respond following a mouse click on the `<video>` element, then you need to explicitly set the input focus, so that your existing logic can then handle the keydown events.

```
document.getElementById("play-video").onmousedown = function (e){ 
    console.log("focus now on video")
    document.getElementById("play-video").focus()
}
```

However, be aware that visually the `<video>` element will be highlighted to indicate selection, and if the user presses <kbd>tab</kbd> then the focus will cycle through the selectable parts of the `<video>` element.

One possible solution would be to bing the `keydown` to the `document` as a whole, so you don't need to worry about where the actual user focus us to get the events (though if you have other input fields on the page, that may add additional complications)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of this line `console.log('code 65') break;`. It will throw unexpected syntax.

In this demo select/focus the video element using `tab` key.Once it is selected then and only then `keydown` event can be fired on t

```js
document.querySelector("video").onkeydown = function(e) {

  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 65:
      console.log('code 65'); //Changed here
      break;c//Changed here
  }
}
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I forgive, you have to make a line break by not having '; ' But the Cuestien is the following that the focus of the mouse you have to be in the video and is there where you should trigger the action of onkeydown.